# Visual composer elements cannot be edited in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have purchased Jupiter theme and i have been using it for a number of website. But recently i am not able to work on the theme because the theme default plugin Visual composer is not working properly. When i go to edit page to edit the elements it shows blank and stays idle. I also tried to reduce the version of WordPress to 4.4 but still no use. Can somebody please support to solve this issue. The theme support has expire so no hope on that. And i am not so techie to sort what the exact problem is. If someone can guide me to solve it, it would be much appreciated. Many many thanks in advance.

The following image show the what i have explained

[image]

Comment: if you purchased the theme, you are likely also entitled to get support, so I'd suggest to contact the vendor instead of asking here

Comment: I think you can ask in support forum of the theme. Otherwise it seems like that the issue is with your admin-ajax.php, please check your console for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the compatibility issue of visual composer with the wordpress. If the visual composer installed it not latest there are the chances of conflict with latest versions of wordpress. So you may please confirm that the plugin you are using is compatible with the wordpress version you are using on your site.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i check the version compatibility?